# Injecting arbitrary HTML snippets using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to inject arbitrary html snippets into a DOM node.

The reason I am asking is because I am developing some functionality for retargeting/tracking tags and my advertising partners use different approaches.

Some of them use `script` tags and they behave differently from other tags.

I have discovered that simply setting the innerHTML property on an arbitrary DOM node to the string `<script src="foo"></script>` is not going to work. Sure the tag is injected, but the code is not evaluated. I have to create a script node first, then set the src and type attributes and finally inject them.

I am looking for an approach to analyze HTML snippets and automatically and safely detect the correct/optimal way to inject them. I've already got jQuery, but if there are any libraries out there to make this easier, I'm happy to consider them.

Comment: How about some code to explain what you'd like to do: "analyze HTML snippet and automatically detect the optimal way to inject" is not very clear. Many browsers prevent you from setting `innerHTML` to a script tag to prevent XSS. So if by arbitrary, you mean, set it to a script tag, you shouldn't allow that. You should treat setting HTML and scripts differently

Comment: If you inject a script tag, I think you would expect that code to be run. If browsers do not want you to run external scripts after the page has loaded, it makes little sense why creating a script element and appending it to a node works, while overwriting the `innerHTML` of the same node does not. I would like to create an API that allows me to inject snippets agnostically of such quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "jQuery html string to elements", gave me: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: I just tested the method with an external script and it works so far.

Comment: Well let us now if it does the job :)